# single-line #ifdef in C/C++

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

Consider the following simple C/C++ example:

```
#define FOO
...
#ifdef FOO
  bar++;
#endif
```

OK, now I would like to fit that (and any other similar) conditional into one line for the code readability sake (the code has tens of single-line statements that all need to be conditional each depending on **different** define). Something that, when used, would look like:

```
#define FOO
...
MY_IFDEF(FOO,bar++;) //Single-line conditional
```

The goal is to have a reusable macro that can take an arbitrary identifier and, compile the statement if such identifier has been #define-d previously, and do it all in a single line.

Any ideas?

UPDATE0: the code must compile for both C and C++

Comment: I don't think you can have a macro expand to `#ifdef`s; the expansion isn't scanned for conditionals.

Comment: you can make function and match macro's corresponding value in if condition and do whatever you want if comes true

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the languages. If you want answers for both languages, you can ask separate questions. Pick one tag and delete the other.

Comment: looks like you dont know about `#undef`

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `#ifdef` while expanding macros, but you can totally precheck it and declare empty statement if condition is not met.

```cpp
#ifdef FOO
  #define MY_IFDEF(x,y) some-processing-you-need
#else
  #define MY_IFDEF(x,y) ;
#endif
```

Also check out new feature of C++: `constexpr` this can also be usable.

Comment: This solution does not work with arbitrary identifiers and require pre-defining similar sections for each identifier (which are not necessarily known to me upfront). "x" in MY_IFDEF was exactly an argument for such identifier.

Comment: @RegusPregus yes, as mentioned in other answer you should use constexpr or `if` for single-line definition.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE4: As pointed out by @Alex Bakanov you can't use `#ifdef` while expanding macros, so there is no single line solution for your question which works in all cases. Nevertheless, I hope the idea I wrote here may be useful.

if you use `#define FOO 1` or `#define FOO 0`, combination of `#define` and `if constexpr` can be used. Note that it gives an error if `FOO` is not defined. This program gives 1 as result:

```
#include<iostream>

#define FOO 1
#define MY_IFDEF(x,y) if constexpr (x) y;

int main()
{
    int bar =0;
    MY_IFDEF(FOO,bar++)

    std::cout << bar << "\n";  
}
```

UPDATE: Based on @eerorika's comment to avoid the error if `FOO` is not defined, the following declaration has to be added:

```
constexpr bool FOO = false;
```

UPDATE2: This version works in any circumstances, the only question is that is it worth the effort?

```
#ifdef FOO
    constexpr bool USED_FOO = true;
#else
    constexpr bool USED_FOO = false;
#endif

#define MY_IFDEF(x,y) if constexpr (USED_##x) y ;
```

UPDATE3: C compatible version. Note that in this case in theory it is evaluated runtime not compile time, but the compiler will realize that it is always true/false and generates the code accordingly:

```
#ifdef FOO
    const static bool USED_FOO = true;
#else
    const static bool USED_FOO = false;
#endif

#define MY_IFDEF(x,y) if (USED_##x) y;
```

Comment: Good suggestion. Similar can work without needing `#define FOO 0` by using a constexpr bool variable.

Comment: @eerorika What do you mean? MY_IFDEF(FOO,bar++) always gives an error if FOO is not defined.

Comment: That error is what you can avoid by using a variable.

Comment: OK, You are right, but it cannot be defined as a compiler option

Comment: The point is to define the variable unconditionally, and choose the value based on whether the macro is defined or not.

Comment: constexpr is only available in C++, not C, any my code must compile for both. It was my mistake of not stating this clearly in the question.

Comment: Your C "compatible" code does something different than OP wanted in the question. If OP wanted to use C code no preprocessor is required.

Comment: Well, yes strictly speaking you are right, but the first code also works if constexpr is left out, which is C compilant... BTW: What is OP?

Comment: `_FOO` is a reserved identifier, by the way.  All identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by another underscore or a capital letter are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: if you use `#define FOO 1` or `#define FOO 0`  .    define is for things like  `#define FOO0` , bad style this all

Comment: @Christian Thanks for the comment, I have changed it not to start with underscore.

Comment: Based on UPDATE3, I gather that I can do away with defines entirely and just use const static bool variable in hopes that compiler will perform optimizations... In that case, I would #define MY_DEF(identifier,value) const static bool identifier=value; #define MY_IFDEF(x,y) if (x) y; and then just call MY_DEF(FOO,true) followed by MY_IFDEF(FOO,bar++)